# ggplot: Grouped, adjacent bars of variable width

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to produce barplot in which the width and height of the bars both convey information: the height is the number of hours spent on a task, the widths respectively indicate the perceived aptitude **and** importance associated with the task. I've managed to produce this monstrosity:

[image: Nested Bars Plot]

It's functional but horrible. I would really like to place the bars alongside one another (rather than overlaying them), so that each activity is represented by two touching bars of the same height (=time spent) but different widths and colors. I've been trying to to pass a width argument to this plot:

[image: Plot w/ dodged bars]

but setting 'aes(width = widthVariable)' gives me overlapping bars (similar to the first image) and the following warning message:

"position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals".

Is there a way of grouping my bars by activity, displaying them adjacently and varying their widths?

Here's a bit of the df I'm using:

```
molten = data.frame(Activity = rep(c('Administration','Working with Colleagues','Use of Social Media','Leadership Role'),2),
            variable = c(rep('Importance',4),rep('Competence',4)),
            value = rep(c(3.02,1.71,2.39,3.32),2),
            width = c(3.48,3.52,4.01,2.98,
                      3.85,2.34,4.87,3.81))
```

The second plot is this:

```
 ggplot(molten, aes(x=Activity, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge')
```

and the first in something like this:

```
 ggplot(molten, aes(x=Activity, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity',aes(width = width/10))
```

Although I actually made it using slightly simpler dataframe, which I melt()-ed into the one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it - had to draw every bar as a rectangle, adjusting xmin and xmax accordingly.

[image: perfected barplot]

```
wadjust = 5.5
gap = 0.0
minv = 1:length(value) - 0.5 + gap/2
maxv = minv + 1 -gap


minv[1:length(minv)%%2!=0] = maxv[1:length(maxv)%%2!=0] - width[order(Activity)][(1:length(width))%%2!=0]/wadjust
maxv[1:length(maxv)%%2==0] = minv[1:length(minv)%%2==0] + width[order(Activity)][(1:length(width))%%2==0]/wadjust

minv = minv +0.525
maxv = maxv +0.525

minvord = minv[order(Activity)]
maxvord = maxv[order(Activity)]

ggplot(molten, aes(x=activity,width = width/6, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_rect(xmin = minv,xmax = maxv, ymin = rep(0,28), ymax = value[order(Activity)],
            fill = rep(c('#e1de00','#e84619'),len=28))  + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust=1)) + 
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,0.5,1,2),"cm")) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=molten$activity[molten$variable=='Importance'], 
                   labels=molten$Activity[molten$variable=='Importance'][order(Activity[molten$variable=='Importance'])]) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = 0:3, breaks = 0:3, limits = c(0,3)) +
  xlab('Activity') + ylab('Hours Spent') + 
  labs(title = 'Perceived Importance & Competence\nAssociated with Clerical Duties') +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (maxv[1:length(maxv)%%2!=0]+minv[1:length(minv)%%2==0])/2,col='white') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(len = 14, by = 2),col = 'white')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution, but you can create a new column that combines Activity and Variable, use that as the x, and fill by variable:

```
molten<-mutate(molten,activity=paste(Activity,variable))
ggplot(molten, aes(x=activity, y=value,width = width/10)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', aes(fill=variable)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust=1)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=molten$activity, labels=molten$Activity)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this. Maybe I can use scale_x_continuous(breaks=foo, labels=unique(molten$Activity)), then adjust bar position manually (don't know if that's possible though)

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress, building on iod's idea of mutating the original data frame. 
I've made two separate geom-bars and nudged them into one another. I'd really love it if every bar touched its neighbor, but position_nudge() only takes a constant. I'm still getting into ggplot so the most obvious solution in my mind is a recycled 'nudge' vector, akin to barplot()'s color argument.

tldr: Little gaps between bars but reasonably pretty now.

[image: Improved barplot. I've shuffled the labels so that the data remains unpublished]

```
 molten<-mutate(molten,activity=paste(Activity,variable))
    molten$importanceBars = c(value[variable=='Importance'],rep(0,nrow(molten)-sum(variable=='Importance')))
    molten$competenceBars = c(rep(0,nrow(molten)-sum(variable=='Competence')),value[variable=='Competence'])

ggplot(molten, aes(x=activity,width = width/6, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', aes(y=importanceBars),position=position_nudge(x=-0.2-0.35)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', aes(y=competenceBars),position=position_nudge(x=-0.35)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust=1)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=molten$activity[molten$variable=='Competence'], 
                   labels=molten$Activity[molten$variable=='Competence'])
```